# Не применяются медиазапросы с диапазоном

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Если пишу медиазапрос в таком виде - все применяется и работает

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  Styles go here
  #header .h_top_part .t_align_r.t_xs_align_c {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
}
```

но, если хочу включить другой диапазон для определенных стилей, при этом сохранить остальные стили для (max-width: 768px), то стили диапазона не применяются.. Почему так и как это можно исправить?

```
@media only screen and (min-width 768px) and (max-width 991px) {
  #header .h_top_part .t_align_r.t_xs_align_c {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  Styles go here
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А двоеточия кто ставить будет?

```
---------------------------------v
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
@media only screen and (min-width 768px) and (max-width 991px) {
```

Comment: стопудов! описался - спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите использовать стиль для мелкого разрешения экрана (шириной  768px и меньше) и для более крупных разрешений, меняя в них только стили некоторых элементов, вам следует указать стиль для ширины <= 768px без медиа-запроса, а для больших разрешений указывать в медиа-запросе только нижнюю границу.

Пример

html

```
<div id="div1">
    <span>
        123456
    </span>
</div>
```

css

```
#div1 > span {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    #div1 > span {
        color: blue;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    #div1 > span {
        color: green;
    }
}
```

Тест http://jsfiddle.net/2odmkbL4/

Comment: это вы про mobile first говорите как я понял ?

Comment: Что вы в вопросе попросили, то я и ответил в первом абзаце. А раз у вас опечатка, то вопрос можно закрывать.